# How to debug into dll source file from web project

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have web project and window project.Web project reference from window project and I want to debug from web project to source code in window project. Where do I setup to look for debug source code in window project.

I copied all source code from another computer. but on another computer can debug just fine.All that different is where the source file is located. so I think it should have some config in studio that tell where the source file is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the process of your windows project when your are debugging web project.

To attach process:

```
Debug->Processes
```

Comment: I do not have to attach the process when I was working on my old computer.

Comment: Which version of visual studio 2008 are you using? May be you can attach through Tools->Debug Processes.

Comment: visual studio 2008 team system sp1 and I tried attach to process of web project and it did not work

Comment: It should work. Put breakpoint at entry level and see if gets hit.

Comment: It does not get hit. I open window project solution and go to Debug >> attach to process and click on studio web project and then run web project while debug in window project.